# Sharing a DB between Django ORM & Prisma ORM

Tags: node.js, django, django-orm, prisma

I have a Django application thats using Postgresql. At the same time the DB is being used by a Nodejs application (On the Nodejs application the queries to DB are being done using raw sql. For enhanced security I want to use Prisma to handle DB queries on the Nodejs application, I have installed Prisma using npm, next steps are:

```
3. Run prisma db pull to turn your database schema into a Prisma schema.
4. Run prisma generate to generate the Prisma Client. You can then start querying your database.
```

will number "3" break my current DB?? The DB has models created using Django. I would like my DB to remain readable using Django ORM. I dont wish to write new models or change anything using the Nodejs application (Its only for fetching data from DB)

Comment: no, it will not break. The command only checks the db schema and creates a prisma schema from it, which you can then use to generate a client (step 4). Just do not use prisma db push or the prisma migrate commands.

Comment: `npx prisma db pull` would not perform any operations on your database, it would just read the table structure so you can definitely invoke `db pull` command without worrying.